# Virtual base function with template return type: compiler fails at derived class with pointertype as template argument (MSVC 2013)

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, derived, covariant

If I derive from CBaseInterface (see code below) with template Argument T=int*, the compiler fails wirh error C2555. This happens with all pointer types used for T. If I use a typedef instead, the same code works fine.

```
// If _FALIS is defined, the compiler fails, else it succeeds
// (MS Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, 32 and 64 Bit native C++, Debug build).
#define _FALIS

#ifdef _FALIS
    #define PINT int*   
#else
    typedef int* PINT;
#endif

template <class T>
class CBaseInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~CBaseInterface() {}
    virtual const T Calculate() const = 0;
};

class CCalculator : public CBaseInterface<PINT>
{
public:
    CCalculator() {}
    virtual ~CCalculator() {}

    // error C2555: 'CCalculator::Calculate': 
    // overriding virtual function return type differs and is not 'covariant'
    // from 'CBaseInterface<int *>::Calculate'
    virtual inline const PINT Calculate() const final
    {
       return (PINT)&m_Item;
    }

protected:
    int m_Item = 0;
};
```

Where is the problem with the pointer types? I am confused and I didn't find anything in Microsoft's docs that fits at this Situation.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: *FALIS*??? Seriously???

Comment: Looks like the Compiler gave me an error (and that's correct), but did not fail. I failed by myself defining the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is to do with the meaning of `const PINT` in the derived class.

If `PINT` is a typedef for `int *`, then `const PINT` is an `int * const` (constant pointer to mutable int) - which is fine, that's what the base class function is defined to return. If you use your macro then you have literally `const int *` (mutable pointer to constant int), which is a completely different type. The typedef is substituted logically into the type system, the macro is substituted blindly as tokens.

One way to rescue this would be to write `PINT const` or `const (PINT)` (so the binding of the const is explicit).

And you really shouldn't use macros.

Comment: Thanks, that's the point!  
The base class should define a const object rather than a const pointer to a mutable object.